# I can't display my h1 in my Menu.jsx in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good morning,

As part of my studies, I have to create an application (Notimail) for mail receipt notifications by SMS and email.

I just started it. Here is the summary of the project: “A domiciliation company offers a post office box service.
NotiMail is a webapp that gives the mailbox manager the possibility
postal service to send automatic notifications by email and SMS when a letter
arrives in his bench.
On the user side, once connected to their account, the application allows
to acknowledge receipt of your mail.
On the administrator side, we have a dedicated interface allowing you to carry out all
CRUD operations on users and simply send messages
notifications of mail arrival by email and SMS to different users."

I created the different components, the different routes and imported the logo. My problem is that in my Menu.jsx, I created an h1 "hello!" and it is not showing in my HTML when I open my browser

Here is the code of my App.jsx:

```
import Menu from "../components/Menu.jsx";
import InputMdp from "../components/InputMdp.jsx";
import btnConnect from "../components/btnConnect.jsx";
import panneauAdmin from "../components/panneauAdmin.jsx";
import panneauUser from "../components/panneauUser.jsx";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import logo from "/public/logo.png";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
function App() {
  const options = [
    { value: "entreprise1", label: "Entreprise 1" },
    { value: "entreprise2", label: "Entreprise 2" },
    { value: "entreprise3", label: "Entreprise 3" },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Menu} />
        <Route path="/a" component={InputMdp} />
        <Route path="/b" component={btnConnect} />
        <Route path="/c" component={panneauAdmin} />
        <Route path="/d" component={panneauUser} />
      </Router>
      <Select options={options} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

````
My Menu.jsx where is my h1 :

```
import { Component } from "react";

export class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Bonjour !</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```
````

Comment: Which version of react-router-dom do you use?

Comment: I think your Menu.jsx should be the last file to include, so react, react-dom, and the rest of the core files are loaded and methods like render() become available inside Menu.

Comment: It's "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",

Comment: I put components like Menu.jsx last (in imports) and it still doesn't work

Comment: try replace `component={Menu}` to `element={<Menu />}`

Comment: No I replaced and it still doesn't work...

Comment: It’s okay, I made it! Thank you so much ! Subject closed. The answer was that it was necessary to put:

<Route>
<Routes>
<Route/>
</Routes>
</Router>

“Routes” were missing

Comment: Do you have any other components displayed? Does the Router itself work?

Comment: @OlivierRobertDuboille, Glad it's working! React router had some changes to its api in version 6. It looks like you're using version 6, but were writing code meant for version 5. If you're using a tutorial, it may be out of date. For a guide on switching from v5 to v6 see this page: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5

Comment: Yes I have Menu.jsx, InputMdp.jsx, btnConnect.jsx, panneauAdmin.jsx, panneauUser.jsx. Now the Router is working. “Routes” was missing

Comment: Thanks Nicholas ! And thanks SwaD and calm !